# Uploading via service and getting message endpoint not available on larger sized files

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service running on a virtual machine. I haven't changed anything on this server or the service in quite some time. When I try to send up a file through the service that is ~25 mb I am getting this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
DateTime:    1/24/2019 12:22:04 PM
ClassName:   UploadPpsZipFile
Message:     There was no endpoint listening at http://www.myservice.com/xxx/FileService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.


Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at WebStorageFileTransfer.TruckTransferServiceReference.IFileService.UploadPpsZipFile(UploadFileRequest uploadFileRequest)
   at WebStorageFileTransfer.ProgramTypes.SendZip.SendZip_Upload.UploadPpsZipFile(FileParms fileParms)

Unable to connect to the remote server

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
----------------------------------------------------------
```

My app.exe.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
  </startup>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>

      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:02:00">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://www.myservice.com/xxxx/FileService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileService" contract="TruckTransferServiceReference.IFileService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileService" />
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I send up a smaller file, such as a 1mb file, I have no issues. I have tested this on several computers and I get the same results.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things that you can change in order to make it work :

**IIS Host Settings:**

I believe you have hosted the WCF service in IIS.  Hence you need to set the 
When sending large amounts of data you will need to set the maxAllowedContentLength IIS setting (for more information see Configuring [IIS Request Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/))
This value defaults to ~28MB as far as I know.

**Max Received Message Size:**

You will have to change this to some other value (e.g. long.MaxValue).  By default it is set to 64 KB.

**Enable Streaming**

By default the mode of transmission for WCF is buffered.  While sending and receiving all data need to be present in memory - which would not be possible for large files.

Hence you will have to change the mode to "streaming" as shown below:

```
<system.serviceModel>  
     …  
    <bindings>  
      <basicHttpBinding>  
        <binding name="ExampleBinding" transferMode="Streaming"/>  
      </basicHttpBinding>  
    </bindings>  
     …  
<system.serviceModel>
```

Refer [the documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming)